# Win32 C++ DLL function gets garbage values in parameters

Tags: c++, dll, cross-platform, calling-convention

I have a Win32 C++ dll (A) that calls another Win32 C++ dll (B). (B) is loaded using LoadLibrary and contains a method:

```
Draw(HDC hDC, LPRECT lpRect, LPBUFFER buffer, LPOPTIONS options)
```

Buffer structure is defined as:

```
struct Buffer
{
    char*           pData;
    long            Length;
    TCHAR           FileName[MAX_PATH];
    Extension       Extension;
};

typedef Buffer BUFFER, *LPBUFFER;
```

(A) fills BUFFER with filename, length etc and calls the Draw function. The Draw function then uses the values from BUFFER. It all works fine when DLLs are compiled as 64-bit but if I compile them as 32-bit then I start getting garbage values in BUFFER fields in (B). Logs shows that the values are good in (A) but turn into garbage when they reach (B).

I tried changing the Structure Alignment Option /ZpX and calling convention for Draw method (__cdecl, __stdcall) but none helped. I think it is related to calling convention because if I change *Draw* function syntax and put BUFFER as first param then (B) gets correct values. What's going on here?

Function pointer type:

```
typedef bool (__cdecl *DrawFunc)(HDC hDC, LPRECT lpRect, LPBUFFER buffer, LPOPTIONS options);
```

Then in InitInstance:

```
pDrawFunc = (DrawFunc)GetProcAddress(dllHandle, "Draw");
```

**UPDATE**
1. As mentioned above, if I put BUFFER as first param then it receives correct values.
2. HDC being a single numeric value always receives correct value
3. RECT gets incorrect values, very large ones

I believe the problem has something to do with structs. Only structs get incorrect values.

**UPDATE 2**
OK I found out my own silly mistake, the declaration for Draw method had LPRECT whereas the implementation had RECT. My bad, sorry about that.
But I am still not sure why:
1. Other parameters were showing garbage values?
2. Why it worked in 64-bit?

Comment: Are you sure that both dlls are 32 bit ?

Comment: How is `LPBUFFER` defined? How do you declare and initialize your function pointer type and instance?

Comment: @user2451677: Yes because both gets loaded and write file logs in 32-bit environment. 64-bit one won't load on 32-bit Windows.

Comment: Nobody can really help without a way of diagnosing the problem. Please show an SSCCE. Simplified source code for the DLL, and simplified calling code. There's not a lot of point in us trying to guess at this.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I create a solution with 3 projects: library B, that contains Draw(), library A, that has Test(), that loads library B and call Draw() with some Buffer* and application test, that links with library A and calls Test(). Everything works fine, both for 32 bit and 64. Small snippet of Test():

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "A.h"
#include "../B/B.h"

namespace {
LPBUFFER CreateBuffer(const char* const data, LPCTSTR const name)
{
    if(!data || !name)
        return NULL;

    LPBUFFER buffer = new BUFFER();
    buffer->Length = static_cast<long>(strlen(data) + 1);
    buffer->pData = new char[buffer->Length];
    strcpy_s(buffer->pData, buffer->Length * sizeof(char), data);
    buffer->Extension = 0;
    ::ZeroMemory(buffer->FileName, _countof(buffer->FileName) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    _tcscpy_s(buffer->FileName, name);
    return buffer;
}

void DestroyBuffer(LPBUFFER buffer)
{
    delete [] buffer->pData;
    buffer->Length = 0;
    buffer->pData = NULL;
    buffer->Extension = 0;
    ::ZeroMemory(buffer->FileName, _countof(buffer->FileName) * sizeof(TCHAR));
    delete buffer;
}
} // namespace

A_API void Test()
{
    HMODULE b_lib = ::LoadLibrary(_T("B.dll"));
    if(!b_lib)
    {
        ::OutputDebugString(_T("Can't load library\n"));
        return;
    }

    typedef bool (*DrawFunction)(HDC hDC, LPRECT lpRect, LPBUFFER buffer, LPOPTIONS options);
    DrawFunction draw = reinterpret_cast<DrawFunction>(::GetProcAddress(b_lib, "Draw"));
    if(!draw)
    {
        ::OutputDebugString(_T("Can't get address of Draw()"));
        goto FINISH_LABEL;
    }

    LPBUFFER buffer = CreateBuffer("test", _T("path"));
    draw(NULL, NULL, buffer, NULL);
    DestroyBuffer(buffer);

FINISH_LABEL:
    ::FreeLibrary(b_lib);
    b_lib = NULL;
}
```

And a whole solution: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5ei6ros9e8s94e2/B.zip

Comment: First parameter always gets correct values. Its the second and above STRUCT params that contains garbage.

Comment: I don't know - Works fine for me